# The stack code cannot run

Tags: c, data-structures

I am doing an assignment. I have done the code but when I look back, I found that I have missed the one entering the score into valid and invalid stack.

So have I tried to modify the code but the modified code will compile but not run. I don't know why. Can someone help me. Thanks a lot.

```
/*
Question 1
This program uses an array applications.
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



//declare struct node as STK
struct node
{
    int top;
    int element[100];
};  

struct node *valid,*invalid;//declare two stack for valid score and invalid score


int main()
{

valid->top=-1;//create empty stack for valid score
invalid->top=-1;
int size, score[size]; //variables for array purposes
int tempMin=100, tempMax=0; //variables for lowest and highest marks
int i,total=0,validCounter=0,invalidCounter=0,countH1=0,countH2=0,countH3=0,countH4=0,countH5=0; //variables for counting purposes
float average; //variable for average

printf ("STUDENTS MARK ENTERING SESSION\n");
printf ("Enter total number of student: ");
scanf ("%d", &size);
printf("\n");

/*Get Marks form User*/
printf ("Enter MID-SEMESTER Test Score:\n");

for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("Test Score #%d: ",i+1);
    scanf ("%d",&score[i]);
    if((score[i]<0) ||(score[i]>100))
    printf("Error:Invalid score entered!\n");
}

printf ("\nThe MID-SEMESTER Test Score");


for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if ((score[i]>=0) && (score[i]<=100))
    {
        valid->element[++valid->top]=score[i];//write the score into valid stack
        printf("%d ",score[i]);
        total+=score[i];
        validCounter=validCounter+1;

        if (score[i]<=tempMin)
        {
            tempMin=score[i];
        }

        if (score[i]>=tempMax)
        {
            tempMax=score[i];
        }
    }
}
/*Print Valid Score*/
printf ("\n\nValid score: ");
if(valid->top==-1)
printf("Empty valid score stack");
else
{
    for(i=valid->top;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%d\t",valid->element[i]);
    printf("\n");
}


for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if ((score[i]<0) || (score[i]>100))
    {
        invalid->element[++invalid->top]=score[i];//write the score into invalid stack
        printf("%d ",score[i]);
        invalidCounter=invalidCounter+1;
    }
}
/*Print Invalid Score*/
printf ("\nInvalid score: ");
if(invalid->top==-1)
printf("Empty invalid score stack");
else
{
    for(i=invalid->top;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%d\t",invalid->element[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/*Print Average Score*/
average=total/validCounter;
printf("\nAverage score: %.2f", average);

/*Print Lowest Score*/
printf ("\nLowest score: %d", tempMin);

/*Print Highest Score*/
printf ("\nHighest score: %d", tempMax);

/*Print Histogram*/
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if ((score[i]>=80) && (score[i]<=100))
    {
        countH1=countH1+1;
    }
    else if ((score[i]>=60) && (score[i]<=79))
    {
        countH2=countH2+1;
    }

    else if ((score[i]>=50) && (score[i]<=59))
    {
        countH3=countH3+1;
    }
    else if ((score[i]>=30) && (score[i]<=49))
    {
        countH4=countH4+1;
    }
    else if ((score[i]>=0) && (score[i]<=29))
    {
        countH5=countH5+1;
    }
}
printf ("\nHistogram: ");
printf ("\n\t[80-100]: %d", countH1);
printf ("\n\t[60-79]:  %d", countH2);
printf ("\n\t[50-59]:  %d", countH3);
printf ("\n\t[30-49]:  %d", countH4);
printf ("\n\t[0-29]:   %d", countH5);

/*Print Number of Invalid Score*/
printf("\nTotal number of invalid score: %d", invalidCounter);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to S-O. When posting a question, please include a description about what your code is meant to do and what error you got.

Comment: `int size, score[size];` here you use the uninitialized variable `size`

Comment: And you will have another problem here: `average = total / validCounter;` `total` and `validCounter` are `int`s. Àn `int` divided by an `int` will result in an `int`. You need `average = (float)total / validCounter;` And many more problems: `valid` is an uninitialized pointer. Giving up.

Comment: no,  the problem is lies on i assigned -1 to top in struct valid and invalid. Before i included the modified code(valid and invalid stack) the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to manipulate on structures pointed by pointers,
those structures should exist in the memory.

```
struct node *valid,*invalid; // Two pointers pointing to NULL

int main()
{
valid->top=-1;    //  run time error: NULL->top (dereferencing NULL)
invalid->top=-1;  //  run time error: NULL->top
//...
}
```

Possible solution, allocate memory on the heap or stack:

```
struct node *valid,*invalid; // Two pointers pointing to NULL

int main()
{
    // 1.
    // dynamically allocate memory for the `struct node` structure on the heap:

    valid = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // no need to do a cast :(struct node *)
    invalid = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // no need to do a cast :(struct node *)

    valid->top=-1;    // OK
    invalid->top=-1;  // OK
    //...

    // 2. OR use structures allocated on the stack:
    struct node valid_node;
    struct node invalid_node;

    valid = &valid_node;        // initialize pointer to the structure
    invalid = &invalid_node;    // initialize pointer to the structure 

   //....
}
```

Note: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Another problem which you have is here:

```
int size, score[size]; //variables for array purposes

scanf ("%d", &size);
```

`size` should have a valid value when you declare the int `score[size];`

Change the code to:

```
int size;
//..
scanf ("%d", &size);
int score[size]; //variables for array purposes
```

Edit, answer to the comment question:

The uninitialized local variables get an undefined values during run-time.  When you define `*valid,*invalid` locally they are allocated on the stack. `size` is put on the stack as well but in different place now!. Since `size` is not initialized it contains whatever happens to be in that location on the stack. It could be a accidentally a reasonable value, `0`or negative value. In your case the random value is no good and program will crash. This is called UB (Undefined Behavior). Defining `*valid, *invalid` globally does not solve the problem. It was just luck. `size` must be initialized to the proper value to ensure proper program behavior.

Comment: why dun need to cast (struct node *)?

Comment: Btw, I found that when i declare struct node *valid locally(means inside the int main())the code crash and cannot work. Did you know why?

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with pointers declared inside. It is related to undefined `size` of the array `score`.  When  `score[size]`; is define `size` is unknown.

Comment: you are right. the program works well after declare score[size] after getting the size value. But how come i declare struct node *valid,*invalid globally also solve the problem. Please enlighten me. Thanks for your help. you are better than my lousy tutor.

Comment: @TeoPeiShen Thanks! I put the explanation in the answer. It is too long for the comment box.

Comment: Thanks you. Maybe it is a luck that program did not crash.

Comment: @TeoPeiShen Yes, It is just a luck! And, if you value my help you can upvote my answer and accept it. I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @TeoPeiShen You did it!  Also you can click the ^ arrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is enough for your program to invoke Undefined Behaviour:

```
// 1
struct node *valid,*invalid;//declare two stack for valid score and invalid score


int main()
{

// 2
valid->top=-1;//create empty stack for valid score
invalid->top=-1;
```

At (1), you declare two pointers to `struct node`, but let them unintialized. As they have static storage, the compiler will default initialize them to NULL.

At (2), you dereference the NULL pointers which is formally UB.

A quick fix could be:

```
struct node _valid, _invalid;
struct node valid = &_valid, invalid = &_invalid;
```

but you should wonder whether the indirection is relevant...

And there are other problems as you have been told in comments:

- `int size, score[size];` uses the uninitialized variable size
- probably others ...

Comment: how about this? valid=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); I add this both for struct node valid and invalid but cannot work too. Please explain to me.